# Why is saving many to many relationship in laravel only saving the first item of the collection?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

Currently I am creating an API in laravel. The models are as follows:

- Offer

  - Offer belongsToMany Days
- Day

  - Day belongsToMany Offers
- Type

  - BelongsTo Offer

Models for days and offers:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Offer extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'offers';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden  = ['map_location', 'regular', 'name', 'distance_to_offer'];
    protected $fillable = ['id','venue_id','type_id','day','venue_address','is_featured','repeater_days','image', 'venue_description', 'offer_headline','offer_subheader','offer_terms','venue_phone_number','venue_website', 'venue_name', 'venue_headline','venue_description','venue_latitude','venue_longitude','offer_when','offer_end_time','offer_start_time','offer_start_date','offer_end_date','featured_date','current_time','current_date'];
    public static $rules = array(
        'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,bmp,gif,svg'
    );
    protected $casts = [
        'is_featured' => 'boolean',
        'is_regular' => 'boolean',
        'offer_when' => 'array'
    ];


    /**
     * Get the offers for the offer.
    */
    public function days()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Day','day_offer', 'offer_id', 'day_id');
    }

    public function types()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Type', 'offer_type');
    }

}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Day extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the offer days for the offer.
     */

    public function offers()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Offer');
    }
}
```

In the database we have days, offers and types. We have the following pivot tables for the relationships:
day_offer

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDayOfferPivotTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('day_offer', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('day_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('day_id')->references('id')->on('days')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('offer_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('offer_id')->references('id')->on('offers')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->primary(['day_id', 'offer_id']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('day_offer');
    }
}
```

offer_type:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateOfferTypePivotTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('offer_type', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('offer_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('offer_id')->references('id')->on('offers')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('type_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('types')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->primary(['offer_id', 'type_id']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('offer_type');
    }
}
```

In my OffersController I have the standard methods of create, store, update etc and when in the create method I have got the days listed in a select dropdown with multiple select values allowed when saving to offer as follows:

_form.html.erb:

```
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::select('days[]', $days, (isset($offer)) ? $offer->days->lists('id')->toArray() : null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple' => true]); !!}
</div>
```

In the controller I use this in the create method:

```
public function store(Request $request, Offer $offer)
    {

        $offerId = $offer['id'];
        $mytime = Carbon::now('Europe/London');
        $currentTime = $mytime->format('h:ia');

        $data = Input::except('image');
        $validation = Validator::make($data, Offer::$rules);

        if ($validation->fails()) {
            return redirect('offers')->with('message', $validation->errors());
        } else {

$offer = new Offer($request->input());
            $day = Day::find($request->day);
            $type = Type::find($request->type);
            $file = Input::file('image');
            $filename = date('Y-m-d-H')."-".$file->getClientOriginalName();

            $path = public_path('images/offers/' . $filename);
            Image::make($file->getRealPath())
              ->save($path);

$offer->save();
            $offer->days()->sync( $request->get('days') ); 
            $types = $offer->types()->save($type);

}
```

The issue I am having with this is its only saving one day out of what was selected in the select dropdown not all of them.

Can anyone tell mw where I might be going wrong with this?

Thanks,
Mark